# Using attribute inspector for ArcGIS JavaScript API?

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, arcgis-online

I'm using the attribute inspector for ArcGIS JavaScript API. I don't know what code will I use, I want to have a dropdown box that is editable with options of red and green, if I select a box, the edit form will show and if I choose red, the selected box color will become red
[image]

Comment: it would be usefull for us to help you if you could post your code

Comment: Sorry but with such description we cannot do anything...
Which ArcGIS-JS-API version are you using? 
Tip: If you would like to change element colours, you will have to use css

Answer (score 0):

The options for your data is typically set up when you create your data (feature service).

You would basically set up the rendering based on a field (which would have two data values: "red" and "green").  See https://doc.arcgis.com/en/arcgis-online/manage-data/define-attribute-lists-and-ranges.htm for one example.

Once you later edit that data in your web application, picking the "red" or "green" data value would then update the map you see.